# React button which passes a prop and activates a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and I'm having difficulty trying to get my button to change its state from a function, as well as pass an event back to the parent component.
Basically when I click a button I want it to filter between levels and stay selected by changing it's state but I can't figure out a way to do both with onClick.
I've tried putting putting an arrow function in onClick and putting both functions in 1 function but still couldn't get it to work. If there are better ways to approach this then please let me know.

Inside the parent:

```jsx
const levelFilter = (event) => {
    switch (event.target.value) {
        case "BEGINNER":
            return setFilteredLevel(beginner);
        case "INTERMEDIATE":
            return setFilteredLevel(intermediate);
        case "ADVANCED":
            return setFilteredLevel(advanced);
        default:
            return null;
    }
};

return (
        <>
          <ProjectLibraryFilterButtons levelFilter={levelFilter} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Inside child component:

```jsx
export default function ProjectLibraryFilterButtons({
    levelFilter
}) {
    const [filterLevel, setFilterLevel] = useState("");
    const changeLevel = (e) => {
        setFilterLevel(levelFilter.value);
    };

    const styledButton = {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 106, 245)",
        color: "white",
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="pl-btn-container">
                <div className="pl-left-btn">
                    {filterLevel === "BEGINNER" ? (
                        <button
                            style={styledButton}
                            className="pl-filter-btn first-pl"
                        >
                            BEGINNER
                        </button>
                    ) : (
                        <button
                            value="BEGINNER"
                            onClick={levelFilter}
                            className="pl-filter-btn first-pl"
                        >
                            BEGINNER
                        </button>
                    )}
```

Comment: What does `setFilteredLevel` return in the parent?

Comment: Both sides of your ternary `filterLevel === "BEGINNER" ?` return the same elements. Both say `BEGINNER`. Perhaps it is working but your returned markup is incorrect?

Comment: setFilteredLevel was used to changed the state of the button. If beginner was selected It'll change the style of the beginner button but since I'm using the onClick in the child to pass back the e.target.value to the parent to filter through an array I can't figure out a way to change the state of the selected button in the child component. I'm probably making it more complicated than it needs to be

Answer (score 0):

found a fix for the specific issue I had. I ended up using onClickCapture to trigger my function as well as pass a prop

Answer (score -1):

`onClick={(e)=>levelFilter(e)}`
Please try once this in button.

Comment: `onClick={levelFilter}` and `onClick={(e) => levelFilter(e)}` are exactly the same thing